# Save image in UIImagePickerController

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a small question about how to save a picture in the UIImagePickerController.

I have tried it with the following code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

if (takePhotoSave == 1) {
    takePhotoSave = 0;

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
} }
```

I get no errors, but the image is not saved

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo){
        UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

        //save to document directory
        NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(image.size.width/5, image.size.height/5)]);
        NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image_test.png"]; //Add the file name
        [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file


    }
```

This is everything you need to save to the photos. If you're looking to save it as an uiimage look below:

```
if ([NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self documentsPathForFileName:@"image_test.png"]]) {

    NSData* pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self documentsPathForFileName:@"image_test.png"]];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];


    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, imageView.image.size.width, imageView.image.size.height)];
    [imageView setCenter:self.view.center];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

}
```

Comment: I have to save the image in the documents, to show the picture in the ImagePicker?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that you are not setting a completion target.

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, nil, nil);
```

This works perfectly for me and so should fix your problem.

You can also set a completion target to check that it is being saved correctly:

```
// Save image
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:), nil);
```

// Check if there was an error

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error {

    // Unable to save the image
    if (error) {

    }
    // All is well
    else {

    }
}
```

Hope this helps